# Implementing encryption in cordova application

Tags: ios, security, cordova, encryption

I'm working on a cordova based mobile application for iOS. I've user created data as JSON and images. I need to encrypt both. After googling I found that iOS itself supports data encryption but to utilize that we've to set passcode for your iphone. Is there anyway I can use the native iOS encryption for only my cordova app instead of applying to the complete mobile? If that's not possible what is best alternate way I can encrypt data and images in cordova?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS has a rather complete set of cryptographic functions in CommonCrypto, part of the Security framework.

You can use the AES encryption and the keychain to securely save the encryption key. There are many examples on SO. Additionally there are complete projects such as [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) that can be used.

There is a [cordova plugin that uses RNCryptor available here](https://github.com/cordova-bridge/safe).

Comment: Something happened to that repo. But there is another one available from the same person that uses RNCryptor https://github.com/cordova-bridge/safe